# Copy child collection into parent

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I've been going in circles trying to figure out the best way to accomplish this!  Basically, I have three Models in a hierarchy:

```
Document->hasMany('Page')
Page->belongsTo('Document')->hasMany('Item')
Item->belongsTo('Page')
```

My goal is to gather all related instances with a query on the Master model:

```
$layout = Document::with('Page.Item')->where('status', '=', 1)->get();
```

This returns a Document Collection with several nested Page Collections that each have nested Item Collections.  When I run toArray(), I basically get:

```
array(
  [0]array(
    [document-title]
    [pages]array(
      [page-subject]
      [items]array(
        [item-content]
))))
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
array(
  [0]array(
    [item-content]
    [pages-subject]
    [document-title]
))
```

I've been using several foreach loops, as such:

```
foreach($document as $d){
  foreach($d['pages'] as $p{
    $pStuff = array($p['subject']);
    foreach($p['items'] as $i{
      $iStuff = array($i['content']);
      $input = array_merge($iStuff, $pStuff);
      $data[] = $input;
}}}
```

This seems to create the array I want, but I wonder if there is an easier way, either with querying my models or when working with the collection.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!
-JB

Comment: Please expand on **it's gotten too messy**. Also your blade template coding related to the above model would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry my question was so sloppy.  Basically, I'm trying to do the equivalent of a join using the related models.  Are their methods for doing that?

Comment: Sure, see: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins Eloquent extends on the query builder, therefore you can use all functions of the query builder on an eloquent class.